# Selenium 2 IWebDriver missing UseXpathLibrary?

Tags: selenium

If i use `IWebDriver` to create the selenium session:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

I want to use the fast `javascript-xpath library` with IE, yet there is no 
`.UseXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");`  in the driver object.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I understand [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/XpathInWebDriver) correctly, they are using their own fast implementation by default:</s>

> How XPath Works in WebDriver
>
> At a high level, WebDriver uses a browser's native XPath capabilities wherever possible. On those browsers that don't have native XPath support, we have provided our own implementation. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour unless you are aware of the differences in the various xpath engines.

You can use Selenium emulation as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);
```

See also: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.html

Comment: The Xpath capability used for IE is based on Sizzle library [link](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)  
**XPath is not natively supported in most versions. Sizzle is injected automatically which is significantly slower than other browsers and slower when comparing to CSS selectors in the same browser.**

WebDriverBackedSelenium is mainly for backward compatability with Selenium 1, but anyhow so doing this and then calling **selenium.UseXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");  ** will have the driver use javascript-xpath library instead?

Comment: Well if you call the function on the `WebDriverBackedSelenium`, it should be applied in subsequent operations on that same instance. How it affects the original `driver` I am not sure. Only one way to find out I guess...

Comment: For what it's worth: while developing the tests, we use Firefox. IE tests are run only for 'compatility check' once before every release.